# Firebase - Cloud Function - Deleting data not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

OK I have very limited knowledge of JS/NodeJs so the error may be apparent, but after asking previously had to create a scheduled function I attempted to create a function that would delete all posts that are 4 weeks/30 days old, for testing purposes I made it 1 hour. (Simply because I don't know how to make it minutes)

This is the code I have:

```
  const CUT_OFF_TIME = 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    exports.scheduledFunction_deleteMyPosts = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 1 * * *').onRun((context) => {
      functions.firestore.document('/myPosts/{userID}/usersPost/{postID}').onWrite(async (change) => {
        const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent
        const now = Date.now();
        const cutoff = (now - CUT_OFF_TIME) / 1000; // convert to seconds
        const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('date').endAt(cutoff);
        const snapshot = await oldItemsQuery.once('value');
        // create a map with all children that need to be removed
        const updates = {};
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
            updates[child.key] = null;
        });
        // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
        return ref.update(updates);
    });
 });
```

It deploys successfully, however, nothing happened after one hour or when I hit run now on Google Cloud scheduler. The content I uploaded is well over an hour old. I expect it to have delete the content I have added rather nothing has happened.

My database is structured as so

```
myPosts
  [USERS_ID]
    usersPost
      [POST_ID]
         -The child nodes
```

Is it not working because I haven't got neither the user's or post's ID? Do I need to perform something like a collection group query?

Comment: Your function is not scheduled to run every hour.  It's scheduled to run at 1am every day.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ah my bad, I'll fix that. I've just been experimenting that much. However, the main issue is I cannot seem to execute or run my function, even manually, it doesn't work.

Comment: Scheduled function are not run manually - they run according to the schedule you provide.

Comment: @DougStevenson So the cloud scheduler's "Run now" button is pretty much useless?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in detail what's not working the way you expect.  Your question should have all the code and steps necessary to reproduce the issue.